# Create Azure web app SSL binding using certificate from key vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to add SSL to an Azure web app using a certificate retrieved from the key vault.  I don't see a way to do this via the portal so I've have been trying to do it with the Azure API.

I'm able to get the certificate secret and convert it to a X509 certificate using the following code:

```
 AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
 KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

 SecretBundle secret2 = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(KEY_VAULT_IDENTIFIER);
 string pass = null;
 X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(secret2.Value), pass, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I honestly don't know what to do next.  I've been looking into the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent library but haven't been able to get anything working.

Am I headed in the right direction?  Are there any examples out there that may help?

Answer (score 2):

For C# code, you can make use of [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#azure-management-libraries-for-net)

You can use following 2 Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent

**Authentication**

You can read the [guidance here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#authentication-in-azure-management-libraries-for-net)

First step will be to create a Service Principal for RBAC, give it permissions on the relevant resource group and then use the clientId, secret and tenant information in code ahead.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac
```

**Code**

```
        string clientId = "xxxxx-xxx-xxxx";
        string clientSecret = "xxxxx-xxx-xxxx";
        string tenant = "xxxxx-xxx-xxxx";
        string subscriptionId = "xxxxx-xxx-xxxx";

        var creds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
        var azure = Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

        var app1 = azure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup("rgAppService", "MyAPIServiceName");

        app1.Update()
            .DefineSslBinding()
            .ForHostname("MyHostName")
            .WithExistingCertificate("<Thumbprint of the certificate>")
            .WithSniBasedSsl()  // could use different method .WithIpBasedSsl in case that is relevant
            .Attach()
            .Apply();
```

**Detailed Code Sample on GitHub**

[Managing Web Apps with custom domains in C#](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-dotnet-manage-web-apps-with-custom-domains)

This sample does a lot of things like creating the Apps, domains etc., so pick the parts that are applicable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is very close but when I create the service provider using 'az ad sp create-for-rbac' I get an error that I don't have authorization to 'perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write'. When working with my IT person to get access he raised a red flag and was asking why my app would need to access Active Directory?  Is there a way to get authorization to use the SDK without going to AD?  Or any other way to set the SSL binding?